# Pulling gameicons data from excel directly in Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, squib

So I have been working on squib trying to set up stuff but I am kinda stuck and I don't know what the problem is.

```
text str: deck['Power'], layout: :PowerText
```

Is the simple way to pull text from the excel file and place it in the card and

```
svg data: GameIcons.get('capitol').
                recolor(fg: '000000', bg: 'FFFFFF').
                string, layout: :PowerIcon
```

Pulls a capitol image from gameicons website and embeds it directly in the card.
So until this point everything works fine.

However, when I try to write which icon I want to pull in the excel file and call it it doesn't work

```
svg data: GameIcons.get(deck['Power']).
                recolor(fg: '000000', bg: 'FFFFFF').
                string, layout: :WarIcon
```

In the excel file I wrote capitol in each cell under Power and it should embed it into the code just as it does for text str: but in the end it returns error:

```
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/game_icons-0.41.0.20171021/lib/game_icons/finder.rb:22:in `not_found': game_icons: could not find icon '["capitol", "capitol", "capitol", ... and so on
```

Can someone point me to what could be a problem here?

Answer (score 0):

If you've been following the squib guides, deck['Power'] is an array of strings.  [GameIcons.get](https://github.com/andymeneely/game_icons/blob/master/lib/game_icons.rb) accepts a single string as an argument.  You need to operate on the array members individually.  A naive way to do this is to use map, like so:

```
powerIcons = deck['Power'].map( |power| GameIcons.get(power).string)
Squib::Deck.new ... do
    ...
    svg data: powerIcons
    ...
end
```

This naive approach should work in most cases.